# Splitting EEG signal by marker using BrainVisionAnalyser

Tags: eeg, data, electrophysiology

I have recorded a long EEG experiment with BrainVision equipment and I want to split it into smaller chunks based on marker numbers. For example, I want to have the chunk of recording between markers Mk11 and Mk12. Is it possible to do so using BrainVisionAnalyser?

I have tried the segmentation tool (Transformations > Segment Analysis Functions > Segmentation > Create new segment on marker position )but it seems to be based on marker description (eg. S_5) and not marker number (eg. Mk11).

Comment: BrainVisionAnalyzer is proprietary software, so fewer people than usual will be able to answer you. However in the past I have had some good experiences with the BrainProducts customer support. I suggest you ask them directly and share the result here.